# Truncating Spaces in a given string

Tags: c

Input- `Hello World`

output- `HelloWorld`

This is program i have written in c.

But i get segmentation fault.

The logic i have used is, when i found a space i swap that with next character till end then insert a '\0' character

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()    
{    
        char s[12]="Hello World";    
        char *t;    
        t=s;    
        while(*t)    
        {    
                char *p;    
                p=t;    
                if(*p==' ')    
                {    
                        while(*p !='\0')    
                        {    
                                char x;    
                                x=*p;   
                                *p=*(p+1);    
                                *(p+1)=x;   
                                p++;    
                        }    
                        *(p-1)='\0';    
                }    
                t++;   
        }
        printf("%s\n",s);   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

swap out the nasty nested while loop with a call to this function.

```
void siftLeftAtCurrentPos(char* cstr)
{
   while(*cstr)
   {
     *cstr = *(cstr + 1);
      cstr++;
   }
}
```

then don't increment `t` until `*p != ' '`

Comment: now inside while loop i wrote   *p=*(p+1);p++;     thanks a lot...it worked ...but what was happening early...why did it show error.....

Comment: but i was using x as a char variable used to swap...

Comment: @user2712068 when you set (p+1)* to x, you lost your NULL on the last pass, that made your loop infinite.

Comment: @user2712068 not to mention the fact that you overwrote your call-stack in the process... lol.

Answer (score 3):

K&R style copy:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
        char s[12]="Hello World";
        char *src, *dst;
        for(src=dst=s; *dst = *src; src++) {
                if( *dst == ' ') continue;
                dst++;
                }
        printf("%s\n",s);
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: +1 cuz it's a solution that would drive OOP types mad.

Comment: Well, it is just a variation on the K&R strcpy() (the continue can of course be avoided; it is only there for educational purposes ;-)

Comment: @Jim since OOP types would be reading a question on C? lol

Answer (score 0):

Just take out:

```
char x;    
x=*p;   
*(p+1)=x;
```

This is the problem.

Comment: why it is so..what actually happens if i do that

Comment: At that point, you already know that character will be overwritten. It became extra when you copied p+1 to p.

Answer (score 0):

Your inner while loop is an infinite loop. When you swap the space you end up making so that the next character will also be a space.

As mentioned in Jonathan's answer, you can fix this by just shifting things left instead of swapping the values. That said, you can make an even more efficient algorithm that removes spaces in a single pass, without nested loops. Your current algorithm will take quadratic time if you have a string that is full of spaces...

```
char* in = s; //next character to read;
char* out = s; //where to write the next non-space character;
//copy all the non spaces
while(*in){
   if(*in != ' '){
     *out = *in;
     out++;
   }
   in++;
}
//now fill the rest of the strings with null values:
while(out != in){
   *out = '\0';
   out++;
}
```